# Fixed subfield of symmetric rational functions $K(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ under $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, galois-theory, symmetric-groups, galois-representations

> Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $\operatorname{char} K\neq 2$, and let $L=K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be the field of rational functions of $n$ variables with coefficients from $K$. Denote $F=L^{S_n}=K(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$, the fixed subfield of $S_n$ (where $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ are the elementry symmetric polynomials). Show that
> $$L^{A_n}=F\left(\prod_{1\le i<j \le n} (x_i -x_j)\right).$$

**My attempt**: Denote the RHS $E'$ and the LHS $E$, and $f=\prod_{1\le i<j \le n} (x_i -x_j)$. Since every $\sigma \in A_n$ acts on $f$ as identity (as any transposition does not change $f$), we have $E'\subseteq E$. The other direction is more challenging. I tried using the fact that $S_n$ is generated by a full cycle and one transposition, but I am not sure how to continue. I assume there are tricks using the discriminant (or rather the discriminant uses this trick?).
Moreover, is $L/F$ even Galois? I am not sure if it is possible to use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the field $L$ with a faithful action of $S_n$. You have $F$, the fixed field
of $S_n$ and $E$, the fixed field of $A_n$.

Recall the theorem of Galois theory that states that if $G$ is a finite group of
automorphisms of a field $L$, and $L^G$ is its fixed field, then $L/L^G$
is a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. In particular, $|L:L^G|=|G|$.

in this example, $|L:F|=|L:L^{S_n}|=n!$ and $|L:E|=|L:L^{A_n}|=n!/2$. Therefore
$|E:F|=2$ and so $E=F(\xi)$ where $\xi$ is any element of $E$ that's not in $F$.
For instance, $\xi=\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$.

Comment: Very simple, very elegant, thank you. Do you, by chance, know where I may find a proof of the theorem you used?

Comment: @RoyShtoyerman Any comprehensive text on algebra or Galois theory should have it. For instance, it's theorem VI.1.8 in Lang's *Algebra*.